# Ansible when condition: only run the script if the command failed

Tags: ansible

I would like a bash script to run only if the command run into an error, yet I am not too familiar how to use the **when** condition, can someone please help?

```
gaiacli status

ERROR: Status: Post "http://localhost:26657": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:26657: connect: connection refused
```

```
- name: Run the script
  command: gaiacli status
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: gaia_status
  chaned_when: False
  become: true
  shell: sh init.sh
  when: gaia_status|ERROR #not sure what to put in after |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do 2 things, so you have to split them into 2 separate tasks:

```yaml
- name: Run the script
  command: gaiacli status
  failed_when: false
  register: gaia_status
  changed_when: false

- name: Init when script fails
  become: true
  shell: sh init.sh # you can also use the command module
  when: gaia_status.rc != 0
```

Comment: Thanks Lester! Will that work if I want to check if go has been installed? Such as command: /usr/local/go/bin/go version register: go_status shell: sh init-go.sh when: go_status.rc !=0 ?

Comment: `rc` stands for return code. It is equivalent to if you were to run the same command on the server and then echo `$?`. Here is a pro tip: after the `go version` task, add a debug task to print the variable `go_status` to see everything returned by the command.

Answer (score 6):

Ansible's **'when'** command is more or less like your everyday conditional operator, just a little more concise.

Let's take this example from the official [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts) of Ansible.

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Register a variable, ignore errors and continue
    ansible.builtin.command: /bin/false
    register: result
    ignore_errors: true

  - name: Run only if the task that registered the "result" variable fails
    ansible.builtin.command: /bin/something
    when: result is failed

  - name: Run only if the task that registered the "result" variable succeeds
    ansible.builtin.command: /bin/something_else
    when: result is succeeded

  - name: Run only if the task that registered the "result" variable is skipped
    ansible.builtin.command: /bin/still/something_else
    when: result is skipped
```

On the first task, Ansible executes a shell command using it's **command** module, and registers it's output in a variable called **result**.

Right after that, you can see the next task using **result** and checking it with **when**. Interestingly, **skipped/succeeded/failed** are official keywords.

You can use a similar approach on your piece of code.
An alternate approach would be to generate a variable on failure from the bash command, register it to Ansible and then use it in **when**, like in the example below.

```yaml
- name: Test play
  hosts: all

  tasks:

  - name: Register a variable
      ansible.builtin.shell: cat /etc/motd
      register: motd_contents

  - name: Use the variable in conditional statement
      ansible.builtin.shell: echo "motd contains the word hi"
      when: motd_contents.stdout.find('hi') != -1
```

Let me know if it helps, or if you'd like additional assistance.